# php function pull list of file names in directory into a php array

Tags: php, xml, bash, plist, info.plist

How do I pull a list of file names from a directory and store them into an array in php?

How do I grab a value from an xml document?

How do I pull the paths/names of the files in a directory and store them into an array?

AKA:

```
$proj_dir = "~/directory/path/to/project_files;"; // same as output from {query}

$data_dir = "~/directory/path/to/data_files;";

$query = "{query}"; // returns path to project being accessed. current output of $proj_dir
```

Some way to grab the bundle id from an xml file called info.plist and store it into an array. Similar to json_decode()

```
$bundle_id_from_proj = function_to_pull_bundleid_out_of_the_file("bundle_id", '"{query}" . "/info.plist"');

$directories = array();

$cmd1 = # some way to get names of files in data/ directory via bash script
exec("$cmd");

$directories = # some way to pull values out of that array and store in php array

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
     // if title of a directory in data directories = bundleID of project
     if ( $directories['title'] === $bundle_id_from_proj )
     {
          $cmd2 = 'open -a Finder "$directory"';
          exec("$cmd2");
     }
     else
     {
          $cmd3 = 'Sorry! Can\'t find it';
          echo $cmd3;
     }

}
```

Comment: One question at a time unless they are very much related, please. In this case, parsing XML and getting a list of files are not related.

Comment: Sorry! There's  just a lot to figure out.  Not trying to overwhelm anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[glob()](https://www.php.net/glob)** to get a list of files/directories within a directory.

Comment: I tried using glob() and it give me 2 outputs I've found thus far.

1. output:  array();  // an empty array

2. output: no such file or directory exists // then the path

Comment: @AlexCory What are you using as arguments to the function?